# Limit of $ \prod_{k=1}^Nx^{\frac{1}{k}}$

Tags: limits

How can be evaluated the following limit?
$$L=\lim_{N\to+\infty}\prod_{k=1}^Nx^{\frac{1}{k}}$$
for $x\in\mathbb{R}$.
I know:
$$\prod_{k=1}^Nx^{\frac{1}{k}}=\frac{x^{\Psi(N+1)}}{x^{-\gamma}}$$ but I'm unable to find: $$\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{x^{\Psi(N+1)}}{x^{-\gamma}}$$
for $|x|\ge1$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\prod_{k=1}^N x^{1/k}=x^{\sum_{k=1}^N\tfrac1k}$$
The series is divergent, right? Make the conclusion.